# How is the interface being implemented here?

Tags: java, android

This is a code snippet from the android developers website.

```
class Preview extends ViewGroup implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder mHolder;

    Preview(Context context) {
        super(context);

        mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
        addView(mSurfaceView);

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }
...
}
```

Here `SurfaceHolder` is an `interface`, `SurfaceView` is a class. `mSurfaceView.getHolder();` returns `SurfaceHolder`. I know how to create annonymous classes that implement interfaces, and it is possible to do something like

`SurfaceHolder mHolder = new SurfaceHolder{ ... }`
to assign a reference to the annonymous class to a variable name. But how is the interface being implemented in the above code snippet?

[The code snippet can be found here](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is further down the page:

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
    // the preview.
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
    requestLayout();
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

    /*
      Important: Call startPreview() to start updating the preview surface. Preview must be
      started before you can take a picture.
    */
    mCamera.startPreview();
}
```

This is the method defined in the interface, thus the interface is implemented here. For readability, Google's example just splits the class into multiple code segments.

(In reality there's several methods in the interface, all of them defined on that page in separate sections.)

Comment: I can see that Surfaceholder.Callback is being implemented because it is explicitly stated. I am asking about the line `SurfaceHolder mHolder;` which seems to create an object of an interface

Comment: No, the line `SurfaceHolder mHolder` creates a class variable of type `SurfaceHolder`. When you have a variable of interface type, you can assign to it any object whose class implements that interface. For example, if I have `MyClass implements IComparable`, then I can have elsewhere in my code the line `IComparable myComparableVar = new MyClass()`. The important distinction is that the line you're referring to *does not create anything* except a variable. Instantiation of a pure interface is impossible, but reference to it is not.

Comment: so mHolder is a class that implements SurfaceHolder?

Comment: @user13267: More precisely, `mHolder` is a variable which will contain a reference to an object. That object will be of a class that implements `SurfaceHolder`.

Comment: It says `mSurfaceView.getHolder();` returns a `SurfaceHolder` which is an Interface. If `mHolder` is supposed to store a class that implements a `SurfaceHolder`, then what does the line `mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();` do?

Comment: That line will return an object whose class implements `SurfaceHolder`. Exactly what class you end up with depends on the implementation of `SurfaceView`.

Comment: so, looking at the answer by @Budius, after the line `mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();` is executed, I should be able to do mHOlder.LOG_TAG to represent a String `SurfaceHolder` and also call mHolder.isCreating() to return a boolean?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `SurfaceHolder` interface, but yes, you will be able to call any of the methods in the interface and expect sane results (that is, whatever result the interface requires implementers to return). The beauty of interfaces is that you do not know, and should not care in general, what class is performing the work; you only care that you know how to communicate with that class.

Answer (score 1):

`Here SurfaceHolder is an interface`

[SurfaceHolder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html) is a interface, with a nested Interface Callback. And this Callback will be implemented in the Preview class.

With this line you get the Interface of the SurfaceView.

```
mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
```

SurfaceView is the class and SurfaceHolder is the Interface which provides the methods to work with the class. So SurfaceHolder is the Interface which is used like the List Interface in combination of an ArrayList.

The [SurfaceHolder.Callback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback.html) interface has three methods, what I can see from the docs. In the code only surfaceChanged() and surfaceDestroyed() is implemented.

This line

```
 mHolder.addCallback(this);
```

adds the Callback to the SurfaceHolder.

Comment: `public interface SurfaceHolder` doesn't this mean it is defined as an interface?But then again why does it have `Class overview` in the description ?

Comment: @user13267 You are right I get the docs wrong. Well, Class Overview is also the title for an Interface Overview

Answer (score 1):

Google do that a lot on their examples. They don't really show the complete code and not always shows the `@Override`. If you to the actual interface definition: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback.html you'll see the 3 methods `surfaceChanged`, `surfaceCreated` and `surfaceDestroyed`

now if you search in the page (ctrl+F) of your original link for those methods, you'll see their implementations.

**edit:**

I'm very sorry, with your comment now I understood the question.

The trick is that that the `SurfaceView` (just like any class) have a bunch of `private ___` objects inside it, one of them is an object that implements the `SurfaceHolder` interface. With the call mSurfaceView.getHolder(), you're just getting a reference to the object that implements the interface that is originally referenced inside surfaceview.

It's a normal Java thing to create objects of interfaces, but you need to explicity show that interface, for example runnable on thread:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    run(){
       // do stuff
    }
}).start();
```

if you're curious you can see how it's done on the SurfaceView in here, line 694

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/SurfaceView.java

Comment: I can see that Surfaceholder.Callback is being implemented because it is explicitly stated. I am asking about the line `SurfaceHolder mHolder;` which seems to create an object of an interface

Comment: see edited answer. I guess I understood the question and I hope I answered it now.